# How to add options in sublist select type custom field?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have created custom select type department field on a journal entry’s sublist through user event before load script.  I am getting context.mode value as blank. If restrict equal to true then keep all departmentvalues that are sourced in user event script else insert fieldlookup options to the custom department field on journal entry sublist. Now I  am getting departments using field lookup from account record’s department field which is multiselect type. I am trying to insert those departments into journal entries custom department field using client script validate field event. But its adding same options on all lines of custom department field. Also When I try to add account on new line,then I am getting an error as

```
“”type”:”error.SuiteScriptError”,”name”:”SSS_INVALID_SUBLIST_OPERATION”,”message”:”CurrentRecord.getSublistField”,”id”:null,”stack”:[“SSS_INVALID_SUBLIST_OPERATION: CurrentRecord.getSublistField”,” at Object.createError [as nlapiCreateError]
```

Please help!!

```
    function validateField(context) {
      try {
        var currRec = context.currentRecord;
        var sublistName = context.sublistId;
        log.debug("sublistName", sublistName);
        var sublistFieldName = context.fieldId;
        log.debug("sublistFieldName", sublistFieldName);
        log.debug("context-->", context);
        if (sublistName === 'line' && sublistFieldName === 'account') {
          alert("validate field");
          // Get account Value
          var accountid = currRec.getCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'line',
            fieldId: 'account'
          });
          log.debug("accountid", accountid);

          var currIndex = currRec.getCurrentSublistIndex({
            sublistId: 'line'
          });
          log.debug("currIndex-->", currIndex);
          var objField = currRec.getSublistField({
            sublistId: 'line',
            fieldId: 'custpage_department',
            line: currIndex
          });
          log.debug("objField", objField);

          // objField.removeSelectOption({ value: null });

          var fieldLookUp = search.lookupFields({
            type: search.Type.ACCOUNT,
            id: accountid,
            columns: ['custrecord_cp_account_restrict_dept', 'custrecord_cp_dept_selection']
          });
          var restrict = fieldLookUp.custrecord_cp_account_restrict_dept;
          log.debug("restrict:", restrict);
          if (restrict == false) {
            objField.removeSelectOption({
              value: null
            });
            var restrictDept = fieldLookUp.custrecord_cp_dept_selection;
            log.debug("restrictDept:", JSON.stringify(restrictDept));

            if (restrictDept.length > 0) {
              for (var j = 0; j < restrictDept.length; j++) {
                log.debug("restrictDept value--->", restrictDept[j].value);
                objField.insertSelectOption({
                  value: restrictDept[j].value,
                  text: restrictDept[j].text
                });
              }
            }
          }
        }
        if (sublistName === 'line' && sublistFieldName === 'custpage_department') {
          alert("validate field2");
          // Get account Value
          var customDepartment = currRec.getCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'line',
            fieldId: 'custpage_department',
          });
          log.debug("customDepartment validatefield", customDepartment);

          currRec.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'line',
            fieldId: 'department',
            value: customDepartment
          });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        log.error("Error occurred: ", e);
      }
      return true;
    }

    return {
      validateField: validateField
    };
  });
```

Comment: In suiteanswers they suggested that use record.getcurrentsublistfield api if selecting new line, but that api  also giving same error.

 

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4637583684.html#CurrentRecord.getSublistField(options)